# Mysql SHOW CREATE TABLE Problem with default value

Tags: mysql

I have two database and i am compare database with column by column.

Database 1 : `SHOW CREATE TABLE affiliate_action` result is attached on link http://prntscr.com/m3xqe3

Database 2 : `SHOW CREATE TABLE affiliate_action` result is attached on link http://prntscr.com/m3xqjb

So difference is on default value. one is without single quote and second is with single quote.. so i make query like this

`ALTER TABLE affiliate_action MODIFY commission float NOT NULL DEFAULT 0;` so we can remove single quote problem. but nothing happen.

Can someone tell me why its happening

Comment: Too many unknowns here.  Don't insert text into a numeric column, because truncation and other bad things can happen.

Comment: no no i don't know how its convert to string so i want to remove it check my ALTER query

Comment: Your alter query **won't** work, because that would only affect _new_ records being inserted, not records which already exist.  Fix the default value for the first table so this stops happening in the future.

Comment: The alter will partly work: for future rows only. You would **also** have to `update` the table data to change '0' to 0 ... if '0' has been stored in that column in that table.

Comment: okay i will try thanks

Comment: Hello.. i have clear both table data (empty). but problem is still there